# Maintain custom start menu position with ClickOnce

Tags: c#, clickonce

When the ClickOnce start menu is installed, it will install in the usual location - Company->Application. However, we have a few customers that customize the location of their applications, for example, under the Tools folder. However, each time ClickOnce updates, it insists on re-creating the location, leading to two versions. Is there a good way of handling this?

I bet Robin knows.

Comment: You could change your application to be deployed as only available online and then in your application startup code, search the start menu for a link to your application and if one doesn't exist then create a default one.